# Figuring out heights in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a CSS like this:

```
#sidebar {
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #044169;
}
#sidebar-menu {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

(Call it test.css) and a simple HTML file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar-menu">
          <ul>
             <li>One</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I *really* do not understand why `sidebar-menu` is `35px` high, and `sidebar` is `51px` wide. Shouldn't `sidebar-menu` be as high as `sidebar`...?!?

In my head, I think: well, `margins` are 0, `paddings` are 0, so the containing element, `sidebar-menu`, which has `height:100%` (of the container, I would think), ought to be as big as the container!

I am obviously getting something very wrong...

Comment: some html elements have default padding and margins, use this to reset them and see *{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

Comment: I cannot decide which answer I should accept. Juhana's makes sense, but it's not as complete (from a conceptual point of view) as maple_shaft's. Which one shall I pick? Help...

Comment: @Merc If you are in doubt then just accept the one that got the most upvotes and vote up the answers that you liked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified, the parent container div will size itself appropriately to its largest element that has an absolute size, not a relative size.

The div `sidebar-menu` does not have an absolute size, but determines its size from its child, the unordered list with the text "One".  It is because of this that `sidebar` will in fact size itself to 35px high and 51px wide, then its child `sidebar-menu` will fill 100% of that height and the width of its child.

Answer (score 4):

You have an unordered list inside the sidebar-menu element which hasn't been styled. Lists have margins/paddings by default. Add:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Now the sidebar-menu is exactly the same size as its container.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cBvj6/)